# Reactjs, how to display clock without memory leak

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have created a simple clock in Reactjs (16.11.0) which tells the time and updates every second. See code below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './clock.css'

class Clock extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date()
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({date: new Date()}), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }

    render() {
        let hour = ("0" + (this.state.date.getHours())).slice(-2);
        let minute = ("0" + (this.state.date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
        let day = this.state.date.getDate();
        let month = this.state.date.toLocaleString('nb', {month: 'long'});
        return (
            <section className={'clock'}>
                <div>{hour + ':' + minute}</div>
                <div className={'date'}>{day + '. ' + month}</div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Clock;
```

When monitoring the task manager in Chrome I can see the tabs memory increase over time. 
For a site which is supposed to be run at a "kiosk"-setup this is a no-go. My Rasperrypi run out of memory after a couple of hours.

My example app is based on a clean 'create-react-app' with this Clock component added.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this memory leak?

**Update**

The memory leak seem to only happen using chromium (and partly FireFox) on raspberrypi and is reduced for some reason when using this flag "--disable-gpu-program-cache"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any stuff in your app that can cause a memory leak. I also created an example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-paper-8k3ft) with you app, which sets state every millisecond, and the memory usage of the tab with the app is not growing over time (I checked through Chrome's task manager). So the leak is likely caused by something different.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I believe you are right the leak is caused by something else. After a bit more testing I think the problem is chromium on my raspberrypi. My page does not leak in Chrome on my laptop. The rpi on the other hand eats up all available memory during the night. (And your codesandbox killed it in matter of miutes...)